# linecache doesn't work in an if statement?

Tags: python, linecache

```
import linecache
for i in range (4):
    file = open("looptestofreceivingquestions.txt", "r")
    lineq = i+1
    print(linecache.getline("looptestofreceivingquestions.txt", lineq))#gets line q depending on iteration
    question = input("what is the answer?")
    linea = i+5
    answer = linecache.getline("looptestofreceivinganswers.txt", linea)
    file.close()
    print(question)
    print(answer)
    if question == answer:
        print("correct")
    elif question != answer:
        print("wrong")
```

No matter what, it prints"wrong". I'm making a quiz that needs to be able to read questions and answers from a file. the for loop just repeats the code for each question and answer. Also the question and answer are the same, which is seen by the print commands (e.g if one of the questions is 2+2 and I output 4, it will say that the answer is 4 and that the answer is 4). I've used the same file for both the questions and answers and I have each respective one stored on a separate line.

Comment: What is printed on the `print(answer)` line? Maybe even do `print(repr(question))` and `print(repr(answer))` to see the exact differences.

Comment: Perhaps `answer` is keeping a newline character on the end (which you should have noticed when you printed both of them).

Comment: @Sebastian I got this:                 > 1+1=?what is the answer?2
'2'
'2\n'
wrong
2+2=?

what is the answer?

Comment: @Sebastian as I understand the question is "2" and the answer is "2\n"

Comment: Looks like @JohnGordon was correct, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `answer` has a newline character (`\n`) on the end of it; we'd have to strip that:

```
answer = linecache.getline("looptestofreceivinganswers.txt", linea).rstrip('\n')
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.